# Do all functions with vertical asymptotes also have oblique asymptotes?

Tags: functions

I just started learning about asymptotes in my Advanced Functions class, and as I was taking a look at all this stuff, a question came up. Do all rational functions that have vertical asymptotes also have an oblique asymptote? Or is an oblique asymptote only formed when the degree of the numerator is 1 higher than the degree of the denominator, and so only functions with a vertical asymptote with a degree of 1 can also have an oblique asymptote?

Comment: What do you think about $1/x$?

Comment: Take $f(x) = \tan( x)$ as an example. It do not have oblique asymptotes.

Comment: @xbh Perhaps the question intended to consider *algebraic* functions? I’m not sure if that’s the right terminology. But yes—good example!

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I assume you mean the *rational functions*, which is a quotient of two polynomial functions? In that case my example is not applicable here. Thank you for informing me!

Comment: Yes, I meant rational functions, not just functions. I added in the edit.

Comment: Try $x^2+x^{-1}$, has vertical asymptote at $x=0$ and no other asymptote.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with dividing two functions and the bottom function approaches zero while the top function approaches a non zero value.

For example $$ f(x) = \frac {2x+1}{(x-5)(2x+3)}$$
 where $x=5$ and $x=-3/2$ are vertical asymptotes.

Oblique asymptotes happen when your function behaves like 
 a non-horizontal straight line as $x$ goes to $\infty$ or $-\infty$
We find slant asymptotes by dividing the top by the bottom and ignoring the remainder.

For example   $$ f(x) = \frac {2x^2+1}{2x+3}$$
where your function behaves like $$ g(x)=x-3/2$$
which is a straight line.

A function may have both vertical and oblique asymptote but not both horizontal and slant.

Comment: this might be a rookie question, but why isn't the equation of the oblique (gx) = x + 1/3 instead of x - 3/2 here?

Comment: @Korvexius Because $\frac{2x^2+1}{2x+3} = x - \frac {3x -1}{2x+3}.$